# Metropolis Ergodicity

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings, ergodic

I have encountered one last problem with regarding to the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. I know that ergodicity is needed in the algorithm to imply convergence to a unique stationary distribution. But how is ergodicity proved in the M-H algorithm? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You construct a chain $P$ that is derivated from a chain $Q$ with an accept/reject condition.

When $Q$ is irreductible and positively recurrent, so is $P$; now as $P(x,x)>0$ for at least one $X$, $P$ is aperiodic, so $P$ is ergodic.

Answer (score 0):

> how is ergodicity proved in the M-H algorithm?

In discrete simulation setting, one could monitor convergence to ergodicity via root mean square like measure of ensemble average vs time averaged value. After given threshold, one could reach to an ergodic sampling regime.

There is a peer-reviewed paper focusing on this authored by myself. It is called [Effective ergodicity in single-spin-flip dynamics](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.90.032141). It has shown this approach for Metropolis and Glauber dynamics of Ising Lenz Model.

R package [isingLenzMC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/isingLenzMC/index.html) demonstrates this. See its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/isingLenzMC/vignettes/isingLenzMC.pdf).